# How to sync multiple esp8266?

Tags: c++, arduino, synchronization, esp8266, led

I'm making a Led-Controller.
My LED-Devices are esp8266. 
I have a raspi with a NodeJS-Backend running on it. 
Im connecting all ESPs with APs that go to the raspi.
I want to have e.g. RGB Fading synced with every other esp8266.

Can't use an rtc/gps on it, because the pcb is already printed (in mass sadly).

My Idea is to run a Timeserver on the raspi that syncs every esp every 5 Seconds or so - and then Code a fake-clock.

I will sent Ranges for the fade etc. (because sending 1400+ json lines is too much for the esp to handle). Then i have a constant Interval where one Loop is done and so i can calculate what step the device should have.

Any othe ideas?

UTP is too unstable and drops too many packages.

Comment: There are two (well, three) basic ways of dealing with packet drop: 1) Use a protocol which can detect dropped packets and automatically retransmit them (TCP is the normal goto here). 2) Send absolute/full information (instead of partial info that depends on previous packets), and then just send so many you can be reasonably sure that enough get through. Or number 3) Choose a different and more reliable form of communication - which I guess isn't an option here.

Comment: esp8266 has built in RTC. not very good, but it can sync it with SNTP and you could run a NTP server on Raspberry. or use Arduino TimeLib to count time with millis() and sync it with SNTP

Comment: @Juraj that was exactly my plan.

Comment: @Frodyne the problem with utp is that you need good wifi stability - I can't guarantee that. Second the data i send is not really big - but if i would sent it with udp i need to send every single "control-command" - that can get laggy, unstable etc and i don't have time to check the packages etc. So it would be better to just send the control-commands once (json file with a few lines max/min range for every channel + order + interval of every step).

Thanks to both of you guys!